# Pass Object from view to controller using mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

View

```
@if (weekMaster != null)
 {
  using (Html.BeginForm("UpdatePlan", "generalPlan", FormMethod.Post, new {  }))
  {
  <table class="table-bordered">
   <tr>
   @foreach (TermMaster obj in weekMaster.ToList())
    {
    <td align="center">
   <span>  @obj.termStartDate.ToString("dd MMM") - @obj.termEndDate.ToString("dd MMM")</span>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="ObjHid" value="@obj" />
    <input type="hidden" name="startDate" value="@obj.termStartDate" />
    <input type="hidden" name="endDate" value="@obj.termEndDate" />
    <input type="text" style="width:80%" name="weekSession" />
  </td>
 }
  <td>
 <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn-primary" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 } }
```

Controller

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdatePlan(List<DateTime> startDate, List<DateTime> endDate, List<int> weekSession, List<TermMaster> ObjHid)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I am trying pass `Class Object from View to Controller`  above TermMaster class Object pass using input method `<input type="hidden" name="ObjHid" value="@obj" />` but showing `NULL` value if pass single value like  `startDate` and `endDate` then it work fine.

What is wrong in my code? how to pass class object List in Post Method?

Please refer Image
[image]

Comment: Suggest you refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: But what is the point of degrading the performance of your application by attempting to send back a collection of `TermMaster` that your not even editing

Comment: @StephenMuecke  in post method I am inserting some parameter value with textbox value for that I need some value from TermMaster

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense. Are you saying that `TermMaster` has a property which is related to `<input type="text" .../>`? And read the link to understand how to generate a view for a collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by below approach.

Create a model instead of multiple parameters, and use index in cshtml.

```
public class model
{
    public List<DateTime> startDate { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> endDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> weekSession { get; set; }
    public List<TermMaster> ObjHid { get; set; }
}
```

CSHTML

```
@{ int i = 0; }
@foreach (TermMaster obj in weekMaster.ToList())
    {
    <td align="center">
   <span>  @obj.termStartDate.ToString("dd MMM") - @obj.termEndDate.ToString("dd MMM")</span>
    <br />

    <input type="hidden" name="ObjHid[@i].termStartDate" value="@obj.termStartDate.ToString("dd MMM")" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ObjHid[@i].termStartDate" value="@obj.termStartDate.ToString("dd MMM")" />

    <input type="hidden" name="startDate[@i]" value="@obj.termStartDate" />
    <input type="hidden" name="endDate[@i]" value="@obj.termEndDate" />
    <input type="text" style="width:80%" name="weekSession[@i]" />
  </td>

   i++
 }
```

Comment: Wrong - A `<input>` only posts back a single value and `obj` is a complex object (your first input generates `value="AssemblyName.TermMaster"` which cannot bind to a complex object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have amended my answer..:)

Comment: Do you still think my answer is wrong. I know how these binding works. Name attribute is mapped with property. I am not sure about startDate , endDate but ObjHid will surely get mapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind objects to controller from your input. You can serialize object to json. In the controller you can take your inputs value as string and deserialize it.